# Proof that $\vec{v} \in U \iff \text{proj}_U(\vec{v})=\vec{v}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products, projection

## Problem

Let $V$ be finite-dimensional inner product space and $U$ it's subspace. Let's 
assume that $\vec{v} \in V$. Show that $\vec{v} \in U \iff \text{proj}_U(\vec{v}) = \vec{v}$

## Attempt to show

Let's assume subspace $U$ has orthogonal basis ($\vec{u}_1,\vec{u}_2,\vec{u}_3,\dots \vec{u}_n$) when $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\vec{v} \in U$. Then $\vec{v}$ can be written as linear combination when $(c_1,c_2,c_3 \dots c_n)$ when $c_n \in \mathbb{R}$

$$ \vec{v} = c_1 \vec{u}_1 + c_2 \vec{u}_2 + c_3 \vec{u}_3 \dots c_n \vec{u}_n $$

If we take inner product with $\vec{u}_i$ for $i \in \{1, \ldots, i\}$ from this equation we have

$$ \langle \vec{v}, \vec{u}_i \rangle = \langle c_1 \vec{u}_1, \vec{u}_i \rangle + \langle c_2 \vec{u}_2, \vec{u}_i \rangle + \langle c_3 \vec{u}_3, \vec{u}_i \rangle + \dots + \langle c_i \vec{u}_i, \vec{u}_i \rangle + \dots + \langle c_n \vec{u}_n, \vec{u}_i \rangle $$
Then the equation can be rewritten using sum

$$ \langle \vec{v}, \vec{u}_i \rangle = \underbrace{\langle \sum_j c_j \vec{u}_j, \vec{u}_i \rangle =c_i \langle \vec{u}_i, \vec{u}_i \rangle}_{\text{someone explain this?}} \iff c_i = \frac{\langle \vec{v}, \vec{u}_i \rangle}{\langle \vec{u}_i, \vec{u}_i \rangle} $$
Now by projecting $\vec{v}$ onto subspace U, we can write (by definition of projection)

$$ \text{proj}_U(\vec{v}) = \frac{\langle \vec{v}, \vec{u}_1 \rangle}{\langle \vec{u}_1, \vec{u}_1 \rangle } \vec{u}_1 + \frac{\langle \vec{v}, \vec{u}_2 \rangle}{\langle \vec{u}_2, \vec{u}_2 \rangle } \vec{u}_2 + \dots + \frac{\langle \vec{v}, \vec{u}_n \rangle}{\langle \vec{u}_n, \vec{u}_n \rangle } \vec{u}_n $$

Now the projection can be rewritten using the fact that $c_i = \frac{\langle \vec{v}, \vec{u}_i \rangle}{\langle \vec{u}_i, \vec{u}_i \rangle} $

$$ \text{proj}_U{\vec{v}} =  c_1 \vec{u}_1 + c_2 \vec{u}_2 + c_3 \vec{u}_3 \dots c_n \vec{u}_n = \vec{v}$$

---

I've been told that my attempt only shows $\vec{v} \in U \implies \text{proj}_U(\vec{v}) = \vec{v}$ but not the case $\text{proj}_U(\vec{v}) = \vec{v} \implies \vec{v} \in U$. For some unknown reason, I can't exactly think why the reasoning would go only one way in this? Also the part with sum in it confuses me quite a bit. Why exactly these two are equal? I made another [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3327329/show-that-if-vector-overlinev-is-already-at-projection-subspace-u-that) about this same problem but I don't think I understand the answer completely.

Also, feel free to point anything that seems off in my "attempt".

Comment: You need an orthonormal basis for all of $V$, with the first $n$ vectors in $U$.  By the way, you can characterize the projection $\text{proj}_U \vec v$ as the unique vector $\vec u\in U$ with the property that $\vec v - \vec u$ is orthogonal to $U$.

Comment: In the "someone explain this?" part you use the linearity of the inner product and the fact that for an orthogonal basis $\{u_1, \ldots, u_n\}$ we have $\langle u_i, u_j \rangle = 0$ whenever $i \neq j$. I.e. all the orther summands disappear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for a way to solve the problem or are you only interested in fixing your solution? If it's the former, try the following: it can be shown that for every subspace $U$, the vector space $V$ is a direct sum of $U$ and it's orthogonal complement $U^\perp$, i.e. $V=U\oplus U^\perp$. That means that every vector $v$ can be uniquely expressed as a sum of $u$ and $u^\perp$. The projection linear transformation $P_U$ takes every vector $v$ to the element of $U$ that is in its representation. According to the definition, $U$ is invariant under $P_U$ (that's the only if part) and since the image of $P_U$ is $U$, $P_U(v)=v$ implies that $v\in U$ ($P_U(v)\in im(P_U)\Rightarrow v\in U)$.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to solve the problem and also interested in fixing my solution. As far as I'm concered my approach should be correct so far? If not then maybe another approach.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is only that 
$$\vec{v}\in U \implies \texttt{proj}_U(\vec{v}) = \vec{v}$$
since you assume that $\vec{v}\in U$

To complete the proof you must next prove that $\texttt{proj}_U\vec{v}\implies\vec{v} \in U$. (ie start with the last part of your previous proof and show that $\vec{v} \in U$)

You have the kernel of that with your inner product approach to projection, but I think it would pay to be more explicit and show that if $\texttt{proj}_U\vec{v} = \vec{v}$ then $\vec{v} \in U$.

Abstractly the answer proposed by V.Ch. hits on the correct theme